# Opacity/Translucent Canvas - I want to see the activity background "through" the canvas

Tags: android, canvas, colors, paint, opacity

sorry for my bad english.
In my onDraw, I want to set the canvas color as "Transparent" : I just want to see the activity's background behind through the canvas.

That's an exemple of what I want: http://cdn.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Flow-Free-Levels.png?35dc20

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@Override 
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
  canvas.saveLayerAlpha(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), 0x66, Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
  super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: It does not work :( My canvas is still black and opaque (But with less intensity, even on circles and lines). That's before: [link](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/15/1428559603-screenshot-2015-04-09-08-02-36-1.png)   and that's after: [link](http://www.noelshack.com/2015-15-1428559412-screenshot-2015-04-09-07-59-42-2.png)

Comment: Have you tried changing the value of 0x66 to a lower or higher value?

Comment: Yeah, I tried, but there's still the black "background" on the canvas (because i have to do canvas.Drawcolor(Color.BLACK)). It looks like circles and lines are transparent, but not the black background of the canvas. Here's the activity when i change the value of 0X66 to 0X10: [link](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/15/1428587373-capture-du-2015-04-09-15-48-48.png)